# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT' variable

Tags: sql-server

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'...
following code below generation error...

```
DECLARE @A VARCHAR(12)
SET @A = SELECT TOP 1 MBR_ID FROM MBR_IDS ORDER BY NEWID()
SELECT @A
```

Comment: why u create a variable '@A' I don't think u need to declare just for selecting..

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to JoeFletch's good answer, you could use parenthesis `()` to evaluate the query in scalar context:

```
SET @A = (SELECT TOP 1 MBR_ID FROM MBR_IDS ORDER BY NEWID())
```

Comment: Yes. I have used this before too! Works just as well!

Answer (score 4):

You need to restructure your `SELECT` statement.

```
DECLARE @A VARCHAR(12)
SELECT TOP 1 @A = MBR_ID FROM MBR_IDS ORDER BY NEWID()
SELECT @A
```